# promise object in angular2

Tags: angular, es6-promise

in the tutorial angular2, there is two ways to use Promises: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

hero.service.ts

```
            import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
            import { Hero } from './hero';
            import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
            @Injectable()
            export class HeroService {
                getHeroes() {
                    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
                }

                getHeroesSlowly() {
                    return new Promise<Hero[]>(resolve =>
                        setTimeout(() => resolve(HEROES), 2000) // 2 seconds
                    );
                }
            }
```

why function HeroService() just call Promises object directly with Promise.resolve; from where come this object, it's ES6 ?  but in the next function getHeroesSlowly() call a promises with new, why this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.resolve()` is a static method (class level method) provided for common cases, and `new Promise()` just calls the constructor.